# "'null' is null or not an object" error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Right now I'm getting this strange error from IE which is basically

```
'null' is null or not an object
```

The line number it gives is completely off so I don't put much credit into that however I think I narrowed it down to where it's coming from.

```
function openSong(songlink){
     $('#smallbox').slideDown();
     requestCompleteSong('<tr><td>'+songlink+'</td></tr>');
  }
```

The code above doesn't produce any errors from IE, however when I do an AJAX GET request using jQuery then it seems to throw this error

```
function openSong(songlink){
     $('#smallbox').slideDown();
     $.get("getSong.php?fake="+makeid(),{ id: songlink },requestCompleteSong);
  }
```

'songlink' definitely isn't null because the first function I posted works fine. Here is makeid().

```
function makeid()
{
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}
```

Can anybody see why IE is throwing this error?

Comment: FYI, how IE calculates line numbers is like this: concatenate all javascript files/code in the order they appear in the HTML page into a single large file, then count the line number.

Comment: Also, IE developer toolbar would show the erroneous code at the line number from IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed one of the most generic Internet Explorer JavaScript errors. It means that you are invoking methods of some object which is null. While I cannot tell which part of your code is causing this error I can suggest a way to find it out. You can use the developer tools to debug your code - just put a `debugger` statement in your code:

```
function openSong(songlink){
 debugger;
 // rest of the code
}
```

Then enable debugging from the IE developer toolbar and refresh your page.

Comment: ok after using the debugger in IE I found that the error is coming from an embed flash player I'm using. So there is nothing wrong with my javascript but some javascript within the flash player.

Comment: Never used the debugging for javascript. Thanks for your answer